# Jest Test failing for API endpoint with 404 error

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, supertest

- I am trying to test my serverMiddleware in nuxt which has API routes
- It has a single route /api/v1/test which returns a json true

My api/index.js file

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json(true))
export default {
  path: '/api/v1',
  handler: app,
}
```

- Here is my api.spec.js file which contains the test returning 404
- If I test my route / it returns a 200

My test/backend/api.spec.js file

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt'
import supertest from 'supertest'

// We keep the nuxt and server instance
// So we can close them at the end of the test
let nuxt = null

// Init Nuxt.js and create a server listening on localhost:4000
beforeAll(async () => {
  const config = {
    dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    rootDir: resolve(__dirname, '../', '../'),
    mode: 'universal',
  }

  nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  await new Builder(nuxt).build()

  await nuxt.server.listen(3000, 'localhost')
}, 30000)

// Close server and ask nuxt to stop listening to file changes
afterAll(() => {
  nuxt.close()
})

describe('GET /api/v1/test', () => {
  test('returns status code 200', (done) => {
    supertest(nuxt.server.app).get('/api/v1/test').expect(200, done)
  })
})
```

My jest.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue',
  ],
}
```

Can someone kindly suggest why the test is failing

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of the jest configuration.

my jest.config.js

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
```

api.test(spec).file requires `node` environment.
I didn't modify it. Instead, I modified the api.test.js file.

I just added the comment code below at the head of the file.
solved) my api.test.js

```
/**
* @jest-environment node
*/
```

link : https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string